# Buscar en un DataFrame a partir de variables en su nombre

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe, por ejemplo: *df_ab_25*

y quiero hacer lo siguiente:

```
letras = "ab"

numero = "25"

ultimodato = df_{letras}_{numero}.iloc[-1]
```

¿Como hago eso?

Comment: Usando `eval`, aunque no deberías de hacer eso. Lo mejor es que tengas un diccionario

Comment: Necesito usar un df porque tengo que hacer cálculos en el mismo.

Muchas gracias por pronta respuesta, me fue de ayuda.

Comment: Nunca dije que no usaras un dataframe, sino que deberías tener un diccionario que contenga los dtaframes algo así `dfs = {"df_ab_25": tu_df, "df_ab26": otro_df}` así solo harías `dfs.get(f"df_{letras}_{numero}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución gracias a mi Tocayo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/183782/christian

```py
letras = "ab"

numero = "25"

previa = f'df_{letras}_{numero}'

ultimodato = eval(previa).iloc[-1]
```

Comment: Cuando tenes la misma variable seguida de distintas constantes, conviene mas usar un diccionario. Eval puede ejecutar cualquier xosigo (incluso malicioso). Al menos si vas a hacer eso, te recomiendo evitar poner una cadena creada por el usuario alli.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código resolvió tu planteamiento. ¿Qué te ha dicho _Christian_? Los comentarios son efímeros. Lee [answer], y luego no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta, cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.